# What is a way to convert text to a string in Python 3.3.0

Tags: python-3.3

Hi so i'm having a hard time getting Text from my program on Python to convert to a string so i can write it to a file without it just writing numbers in the file. i put this code :

```
from tkinter import *

a = Tk()
a.title("i need help")
a.geometry("600x600")

entryText = StringVar(None)

codeEdit = Text(a)
codeEdit.insert(END, "")
codeEdit.pack(side='top')

text = str(codeEdit)

def setLoc():
    saveFile = open("DATA\Test.txt", "w")
    saveFile.write(text)
    saveFile.close()


    return 

writeButton = Button(text="Write",command=setLoc)
writeButton.pack(side='bottom')
```

so thats the code to write the obj locFile to the file Test.txt but when i type something in the Text box on the program and hit the writButton it will write to the file just not what i typed in it puts .50132192 so i wanted to know how i could convert it to a String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `Text` widget's `get` method to get all of the text from `'1.0'` (line 1, character 0) to `END`.

Here's a modified version of your code that does this in a `write_text` function. I also added scroll bars and switched to using `grid` instead of pack.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def write_text():
    text = edit.get('1.0', END)
    with open("DATA/Test.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(text)

root = Tk()
root.title("This May Help")
root.geometry("600x600")

edit = Text(root, width=80, height=25, wrap=NONE)
edit.insert('1.0', '[enter text]')
edit.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))

yscroll = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL, command=edit.yview)
yscroll.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(N,S))
edit['yscrollcommand'] = yscroll.set

xscroll = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=edit.xview)
xscroll.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(W,E))
edit['xscrollcommand'] = xscroll.set

write_button = Button(text="Write", command=write_text)
write_button.grid(column=0, row=2)
```

Comment: Thank you i used the .get() and i always got error's but i didn't put the '1.0' in text = edit.get('1.0', END)  and i completely forgot about the f so thank you ^.^